# google card board screen shaking in some android devices

Tags: google-cardboard

Cardboard app not working properly the screen shaking in some android device .one of my test app working properly in Nexus4,Nexus5 and when i test the app in Moto G(2 gen) which has the gyroscope doesn't have NFC is not working properly .facing the screen shaking issue rest of the things working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd gen Moto G has this issue. Updating it to Lollipop should solve it.

See [this xda thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g-2014/help/super-shaky-gyroscope-fix-confirm-issue-t2961077).